# Is "result" a reserved array key in PHP 7.4

Tags: php

Is `"result"` somehow a reserved keyword in PHP arrays?

I have a script where a variable `$row` contains two values, but acessing the value via the key `"result"` fails:

This happens both when debugging and running the script in an Apache webserver.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [No, it isn't.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php)

Comment: No, it is not. There is no such thing as _any_ "reserved" array key in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned, that I have checked the reserved keywords. That's exactly the reason I ask here, I am kind of clueless.

Comment: Where does $row come from, how does it get created? Maybe some whitespace or "invisible character" at the end of some database column name or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `"result"` is not a reserved keyword.

Thank you CBroe, it was a hidden character:

... makes me want to move into the woods, settling down, living a simple life : )

[image]